# How can I solve the Websockets connection error when running my React/Typescript client with Docker?

Tags: reactjs, docker, websocket

I am creating a simple client/server application and attempting to containerize it using Docker. The client is implemented in React/Typescript while the server is written in Python. The standard Websockets library is used everywhere. When I run the project locally using localhost as the server's hostname, the application works as expected, however when I try to run it on a Docker container, the client cannot connect to the server.

The client uses a websocket object defined as `new WebSocket(ws:/api-gateway/8002)`. However, this throws an error during Docker runtime. If I were to run this locally using `npm run` in my terminal, no issues arise (the hostname is obviously changed to `localhost` in this case).

To diagnose this error, I have run the docker containers using `docker-compose up`. In my client container, I use `wscat` to try to connect to the server. This works, demonstrating that the hostname `api-gateway` is visible to the client.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.